# How to conditionally insert element in XML using MuleSoft DataWeave 2.0

Tags: xml, dataweave, mulesoft, mule4

My input xml is :

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<HRPeopleMaster>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeID>123456</EmployeeID>
    <LastName>surname1</LastName>
    <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeID>56789</EmployeeID>
    <LastName>surname2</LastName>
    <FirstName>xyz</FirstName>
  </Employee>
 </HRPeopleMaster>
```

I have a variable which contains a JSON array:

```
`var hroutput = [ {"customString": "10526","userId": "123456"},{"customString": "10551","userId": "45678"}]`
```

I want to insert the field customstring from this variable into the above xml only if the vars.hroutput.userId == Employee.EmployeeID condition is met.

So the final output should look like this:

```
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<HRPeopleMaster>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeID>123456</EmployeeID>
    <LastName>surname1</LastName>
    <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
    <customString>10526</customString>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeID>56789</EmployeeID>
    <LastName>surname2</LastName>
    <FirstName>xyz</FirstName>
    <customString/>
  </Employee>
 </HRPeopleMaster>`
```

Please guide me on how I can achieve this in a dataweave 2.0 script of Mulesoft

I tried to use the filter condition :

```
`{
    HRPeopleMaster: {
        (payload.HRPeopleMaster.*Employee map ( employee , indexOfEmployee ) -> {
            Employee: { FirstName: employee.FirstName
            } ++ (customString: (hroutput.customString) filter (hroutput.userId contains employee.EmployeeID)) 
        })
    }
}`
```

The output was like this:

```
`<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<HRPeopleMaster>
  <Employee>
    <FirstName>Rajan</FirstName>
    <customString>10526</customString>
    <customString>10551</customString>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <FirstName>Eamon</FirstName>
    <customString/>
  </Employee>
</HRPeopleMaster>`
```

Comment: Please remove the extra single quotes in samples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is via Join from Arrays module, like below:

```
%dw 2.0
import leftJoin from dw::core::Arrays
var hroutput = [
  {
    "customString": "10527",
    "userId": "1234546"
  },
  {
    "customString": "10526",
    "userId": "123456"
  },
  {
    "customString": "10551",
    "userId": "45678"
  }
]
output application/xml
---

  HRPeopleMaster: 
    Employee: leftJoin(payload..*Employee, hroutput, (empID) -> empID.EmployeeID, (hrUserId) -> hrUserId.userId) map {
      ($.l),
      (
        customString: ($.r.customString)
      )
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is important to understand that DataWeave doesn't process internally as XML or JSON. It parses the input into its internal format, transforms it, then it writes the output to the output format. Because in XML there are no lists, all `Employee` elements are internally keys of the `HRPeopleMaster` element. Once we know that we can think of a transformation as:

- We need to update only the Employees under the root element.
- For each
  key inside that, if the value (which is an object) of EmployeeID is
  contained in the variable then upsert it into the value.

Using the [update operator](https://docs.mulesoft.com/dataweave/2.4/dw-operators#update-operator) simplifies the script.

```js
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
var hroutput = [ {"customString": "10526","userId": "123456"},{"customString": "10551","userId": "45678"}]
---
payload update {
    case employees at .HRPeopleMaster -> 
        employees mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
            (key): value update {
                case custom at .CustomString! if (hroutput.*userId contains value.EmployeeID ) -> (hroutput dw::core::Arrays::firstWith($.userId == value.EmployeeID)).customString
            }
        )
}
```

Output:

```json
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<HRPeopleMaster>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeID>123456</EmployeeID>
    <LastName>surname1</LastName>
    <FirstName>abc</FirstName>
    <CustomString>10526</CustomString>
  </Employee>
  <Employee>
    <EmployeeID>56789</EmployeeID>
    <LastName>surname2</LastName>
    <FirstName>xyz</FirstName>
  </Employee>
</HRPeopleMaster>
```

Comment: You should upvote/accept useful answers to mark them to other users of the site.

Comment: Nice one aled 

Comment: any feedback on below script. I am not adding it as answer, as yours is clearly better.



%dw 2.0
output application/xml
var hroutput = [{"customString": "10526","userId": "123456"},{"customString": "10551","userId": "45678"}]

fun lookupfun(empId: String): String = 
  if((hroutput.userId) contains empId) 
  (hroutput filter ((item, index) -> item.userId contains  empId)) [0].customString
  else
   ''
---
HRPeopleMaster:
(Employee:( (payload.HRPeopleMaster.*Employee) map (v1,k1) ->
{
    Employee:v1 ++ {'customString': lookupfun(v1.EmployeeID as String)}
})..Employee)

Comment: Please do not ask questions in comments. If you have a specific issue please open a new question.

Answer (score 0):

One more way to solve this.

```
%dw 2.0
output application/xml
var  hroutput = [ {"customString": "10526","userId": "123456"},{"customString": "10551","userId": "45678"}]
 
var hrMapping ={(hroutput map (
    ($.userId) : $.customString
))}
---
HRPeopleMaster : payload.HRPeopleMaster mapObject ((value, key, index) -> 
    (key) : value ++ {customString: hrMapping[value.EmployeeID]}
)
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be adding conditionally as requested.